# KVM Functionality

Tags: kvm-switch

I want to buy a KVM and I don't know if the video cables are required to be connected in order for the KVM Switch to work. For my current setup I only need mouse and keyboard switching.

I tried an old KVM and failed. Must the video cables be connected in order for the KVM switch to work properly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

From some things I'm reading after searching Google for "kvm without video", it sounds like that will work. However, if you only want keyboard/mouse switching, you might try [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/), which connects computers over the network and lets you simply move the mouse from one screen to another to switch where your input goes. (For Macs, a similar program called [teleport](http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/) is better than the Mac version of Synergy).

Comment: Synergy is great, and i use it all the time, but you still occasionally need to switch the keyboard/mouse, otherwise how would you boot the individual computers and get synergy going in the first place?  Yes, most KVMs work fine without the video connected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer fits all and it depends on brand and model.

I have a ~10 year old 4 port Belkin I use which requires no external power and "comes alive" after I power in any PS/2 keyboard from a pc.

I have another one which requires to be plugged in to a socket before anything works.

Again, there is just no way to know! If you have one in particular you are thinking of buying, I would email the manufacturer and ask. That is what pre sale support is about and unless someone has personal experience with the same model, it is doubtful anyone will know